# Neovim - Run an external command in nvterm, reload the current file once completed

Tags: neovim, external-command

What I am trying to do in Neovim is to open an Nvterm window, send a command (`sleep` in the example below) to it, wait until it finishes and the window is closed. Then reload the current buffer. Where I got so far is:

```lua
-- see if there is any terminal-type buffer around
function Find_terminal_buffer()
  local terminal_buffer = nil
  local buf_list = vim.api.nvim_list_bufs()
  for _, buf in ipairs(buf_list) do
    local buf_name = vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(buf)
    if vim.startswith(buf_name, 'term://') then
      terminal_buffer = buf
      break
    end
  end
  return terminal_buffer
end
..
require("nvterm.terminal").send("sleep 3 && exit", "float")
vim.wait(9000, function() return Find_terminal_buffer() == nil end, 500)
vim.cmd('e')
```

Sadly this approach does not do the job. I know I could probably achieve the goal by using `--remote` but maybe there is some other - better way?